# Using NMAP to find hostnames

Tags: ip, hostname, nmap

This may be a dumb question but i have to ask. I hav several IP addresses for devices in our network that i need the hostnames for. I want to use nmap to get these hostnames, however, when i run a ping scan, intense scan, etc.....it never pulls up the host name. Is this not possible?

I have tried ping scans
Intense scans
& Slow comprehensive scan

Is there something im missing? I heard that this was possible through nmap, i feel like im just missing a very simple detail.

Answer (score 0):

the only **nmap** single line output is for "[host down]" message, so first filtering for the "scan report" lines only then filtering out lines having hosts down, the rest would be listed hostnames with their IPs:

`nmap -v -sn 192.168.114.0/24|grep "scan report"|grep --invert-match "host.down"`